# Set default value for "Additional CSS class(es)" for specific block types

Tags: filters, hooks, block-editor

For the `columns` block type, I'd like to add in a default value of `wp-block-columns--padded` in the "Additional CSS class(es)" field, the idea being that the user could remove or modify the class as needed (i.e. removing it to disable all padding, changing it `wp-block-columns--padded-extra` for additional padding, etc.). Is it possible to do this via a filter or something similar? I did look in to `wp.hooks.addFilter`, but that didn't allow the user to edit the classes that I added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to register custom **block style variations** for the `core/columns` block and let the user select your custom padding settings from these, instead of editing class names in the extra classes field (which isn't too comfortable from a user's perspective). Gutenberg automatically outputs class names in the form `is-style-(name of block style variation)` when a variation is selected and you can also set a default one. You can do it with JS, more info here: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/#block-style-variations

Or, quite simply, with PHP: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/#server-side-registration-helper

But if you need some granular control style variations are not the right solution.

More "premium" would be to add a custom **Inspector Controls panel** for your padding settings in the block sidebar with `wp.hooks`. But you will need to write hooks for `settings` with `blocks.registerBlockType` (for your custom padding attribute(s)), for `edit` with `editor.BlockEdit` (the sidebar controls' logic and maybe editor classes - if you want to show the changes on-the-fly in the editor) and for `save` with `blocks.getSaveElement`( to bring your classes to frontend). Much fun but way more work ;)

Starting point: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/#filters

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get it functioning in a reasonable way with `register_block_style`. JavaScript options sound interesting too, but we'll leave that for another day. 